# Manual String Replace (Free Pascal)

Tags: pascal

I am trying to replace a word in a string without using StringReplace, any idea how?

I am using 4 text boxes.

1st box is original text
2nd box is the search word
3rd box is the replace word
4rd box is the outcome text

```
var
  Form1: TForm1;
  result: string;
  rep: string;
  i, iCount: integer;  


procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Edit4.Text := StringReplace(Edit1.Text, Edit2.Text, Edit3.Text, [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
  begin
    result := Edit4.Text;
    rep := Edit3.Text;
    iCount := 0;

    for i := 1 to length(result) do
    begin
      if result[i] = rep then
        inc(iCount);
    end;
  end;
  label5.Caption := ('There was ' + IntToStr(iCount) + ' changes made');
end;
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Updated** It doesn't seem to want to count with the string replace function

Comment: You say: *...without using StringReplace*, but your code **is using** `StringReplace()`? What is the real problem? Do you want to avoid `StringReplace()` or do you want to have the count of replacements or both?

Comment: I can not get it to work with StringReplace so was thinking of an alternative. Yes I do want it to count the replacements but not able to get it to work.

Comment: Ok, I'll prepare an answer, but remember for future not to ask how to solve x when y is your actual problem.

Comment: @TomBrunberg:  My apologies, I posted a quick answer just before your comment appeared.  Hopefully yours will be better than mine.

Comment: @Martyn He, he. I ditched my halfready answer already. I will now, how do you say, scrutenise your answer with a magnifier!

Answer (score 2):

This should do something like you want:

```
program mystringreplacetest;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

uses
  {$IFDEF UNIX}{$IFDEF UseCThreads}
  cthreads,
  {$ENDIF}{$ENDIF}
  Classes, SysUtils;


function MyStringReplace(const Input, Find, Replace : String; out Count : Integer) : String;
var
  P : Integer;
begin
  Count := 0;

  Result := Input;

  repeat
    P := Pos(Find, Result);
    if P > 0 then begin
      Delete(Result, P, Length(Find));
      Insert(Replace, Result, P); 
      Inc(Count);
    end;
  until P = 0;
end;


var
  S : String;
  Count : Integer;
begin
  S := 'a cat another cat end';
  S := MyStringReplace(S, 'cat', 'hamster', Count);
  writeln(S, ' : ', Count);
  readln;
end.
```

In case this is homework, I've left a couple of things for you to do:

- Case insensitivity
- Avoiding repeated scanning the characters up to the first occurrence of `Find`.

Obviously, it would be good if you read up on the `Pos` function and the `Delete` and `Insert` procedures for future reference.

**PS:**  Beware that this code contains a trap for the unwary.  Consider what happens when the `Replace` string contains the `Find` one (e.g. Find = 'cat' and Replace = 'catflap').  Can you see what the problem would be, and how to avoid it?

Comment: You were faster :). I was trying to formulate an answer without code, in case it is homework, but it would have been much faster to just write the code. Cheers!

Comment: Did this answer your q?